# Why alert function not working when loading with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Lufia</title>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function ajax()
 {

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET",'welcome.html',true);
xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script></head>
<body>


<button onclick="ajax();"></button><div id="mydiv"></div></body>
</html>
```

And another page called welcome.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Lufia</title>

<body onload="alert('ank');">welcome
</body>
</html>
```

I want it to alert ank when welcome.html is loading via ajax as alert function is written on body onload attribute of welcome.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, the HTML you're trying to insert is not valid. Not only is it malformed (no root element, no head, title outside head), but it's not a document fragment (which is what *most* people return when they load HTML via AJAX).

So the browser is doing the best it can, which includes **stripping out the new `<body>` tag**. Since it gets removed, the event obviously cannot fire.

Why are you doing this anyway? You already have the equivalent to `onload` - you're even using it to put the HTML in your `<div>` in the first place. Just do stuff in there.

Side-note: If you think adding a `<script>` via `innerHTML` will work, here's some advice: It won't.